# Error during template rendering / __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Tags: django, django-admin

I was trying to edit from Django admin panel then this error occure
Error:
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Django\new\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VRDw.jpg)

models.py looks like:

```
class hotel(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
company_PAN_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
registered_owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, choices=gender_choice)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, null=True)
phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
website = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True)
registration_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='documents/%y/%m/%d/')
PAN_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='documents/%y/%m/%d/')
citizen_id_front = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='citizen_id/%y/%m/%d/')
citizen_id_back = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='citizen_id/%y/%m/%d/')
verified_hotel = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.hotel_name

class hotel_application_status(models.Model):
hotel = models.ForeignKey(hotel, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
resubmitted = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.hotel.hotel_name
```

Comment: `hotel` is a nullable field, which means that `self.hotel` can be `None` if no `hotel` has been set. You need to handle that case in your `__str__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your amazing support!!

I solve the above error by deleting the null row from the hotel database. The above error was occurring due, to Null Field. I was using Django signals in this project and when the user is created the hotel is also created with Null fields.

It works fine for Django forms but when you use the Django admin panel to add new data the above errors occur.
[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmfE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you want

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.hotel.hotel_name if self.hotel and self.hotel.hotel_name else ''
```

Comment: No, it isn't, it's an instance of `hotel_application_status`.

Comment: You're right, I have edited my response accordingly.